# How to position an absolute/fixed element relative to the viewport instead of parent with "container-type: inline-size" in HTML/CSS?

Tags: css, container-queries, css-contain

I have a parent element (`#container`) with `container-type: inline-size`. Inside this element, I have a child element (`#absolute`) with `position: absolute`. This causes the absolute element to be positioned relative to `#container`. However, I would like to position it relative to the viewport.

As far as I know, this is caused by the `container-type: inline-size` rule which causes the parent element to serve as the containing block for the absolute element.

`container-type: inline-size` on `#container` is necessary to use container queries relative to the container's dimensions. And in my case, the absolute element is rendered inside `#container` and cannot be easily moved out.

The real-life use case for this is a main app `#container` and full-screen modals that are rendered inside the responsible components (which reside inside the main container).

```css
#foo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

#container {
  container-type: inline-size;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="foo">foo</div>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="absolute">Absolute</div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

The child element (orange) is positioned relative to the parent (yellow). But I would like it to be relative to the viewport which would make it appear inside/on top of the green element.

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block#identifying_the_containing_block (step 4)

Comment: you cannot, the only way is to (1) get rid of container or (2) place the element outside

Comment: Fun fact: a draft of this question was generated by ChatGPT after I explained the problem and it was unable offer a solution. Thanks, Temani - perhaps the AI was correct. However, I do hope that maybe somebody has encountered this problem and perhaps even found a hacky solution.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @VictorSantizo No, as far as I know, this isn't possible. In my case, I worked around it by placing the child outside the container. If containers get more popular, then perhaps some day we'll get a good solution.